# Why were these 2 not an answer flags declined by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, support, moderators, declined-flags

I went to flag an answer just recently, and I get this message that I've never seen before :

[image]

---

So I reviewed my recent flags, and I see that 2 of my recent flags have been declined.
[#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873511/python-word-frequency-count-program/21873574#21873574)
[#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873824/nullpointerexception-getattributecustom-field-from-dofilter-liferay/21873999#21873999)

[image]

---

Was I right that these were not answers, but just like comments?

If I was right, is there anyway to not have this effect my record, so I don't get banned/suspended from flagging?

Also, when I flag for, *"it is not an answer"*, I was under the impression that it goes to the low quality posts queue, where it can be deleted by enough votes to delete. Or do only *"it is very low quality"* flags go to that queue?

Comment: The message is a really recent change. Also, NAA flags don't kick a post into Low Quality - only VLQ flags do that.

Comment: Both of those flags were bogus. That's why mods review them. 90% of them are dead-on accurate and the moderator can just click delete, but that other 10% is where folks need to be set straight. Eventually, we'll probably move these into a 10K review queue (they're already in the 10K flag queue) for this same reason.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Semantically they *are* answers, just not particularly good ones. An answer can still be phrased as a question, as a way for pointing something out in an oblique or polite way (there's probably a name for this but I don't know what it is, [these guys](https://english.stackexchange.com/) would know it).

So the correct action for "answers" like this is to either down vote, comment and ask for clarification, or flag as VLQ (for me VLQ is a last resort, the other two are usually a more direct way of getting an answer improved).

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian No, it's definitely an answer, written as *Have you thought about [solution here]?* In fact he suggests something very similar to the answer from Burhan, but he didn't include any code. For these you are better off encouraging the author to write a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian Do you realize that Low Quality Flags still hit the Moderator Queue?  While a 10k user can review low quality flags as well, they can dispute your flags.

Comment: The example you're using isn't asking for help writing SVG, and isn't being recommended a different product, @Lower. He's writing text to a file, and the answer is suggesting he can avoid his problem by writing it in a different manner. Don't fuzzy up the issue by just ignoring what you flagged and pretending you flagged something else entirely!

Comment: FYI: VLQ flags get reviewed by mods, 10K users, and edit-privileged reviewers (all in different contexts), @Lower. Search meta for details.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian Not every answer with a question mark in it is "not an answer."